# Proxmox at hetzner, do i need post-up echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/proxy_arp command?

Tags: proxmox

I've just finished installation of proxmox (it's my first experience), and started to playing around. I found strange line in /etc/network/interfaces config, could you please say what does it affect?

/etc/network/interfaces looks like following (ip addresses are marked with "xxx"):

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address   ...
    netmask   ...
    gateway   ...
    broadcast ...

    # This line is confusing me
    post-up echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/proxy_arp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the activation of arp proxying on eth0, to avoid confusing some network devices or avoid being blocked by some ISP : this way, the proxy answers all the arp requests with eth0 MAC address, instead of having each VM in the ProxMox hypervisor answering with its own virtual MAC address. Some devices or ISP's don't like seing one physical interface pretending to have a lot of MAC addresses.